# Relational algebra natural join Database

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-algebra

Here I have the relational algebra databases:

[image]

So far I have done this:

[image]

The equations are in the first screenshot at the bottom.
I want to know if I am missing out on something because I have a feeling I haven't done the first equation correctly.

Comment: I can't tell if you evaluated the queries correctly since your Customer table overlaps Order so I can't see all the rows.

Comment: Ok. I sorted it out properly all the screenshots.

Comment: Your answer to the first query isn't correct.  Note that natural join only returns rows for which columns with the same name correspond in value.

Comment: Please get rid of extraneous text and clearly label your output with its specification. Show your intermediate work so we can explain where you went wrong. Check out [RelaX](http://138.232.66.66/ra/index.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the Relax link but I figured it out myself and got a good mark on it but thx anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asnwered the question myself. I appreciate everyone reading this.